# What is the best way of counting distinct values in a Dataframe and group by a different column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple Dataframe, that looks like this:

```
    DRUNK_DR    state
11418   0   Indiana
2129    0   California
17876   0   Nebraska
26033   0   Tennessee
25278   0   South Carolina
10565   0   Illinois
30017   0   Vermont
19079   1   New Mexico
21159   0   North Carolina
22620   0   Oklahoma
```

DRUNK_DR can be 0 1 2 3

```
(drunk['DRUNK_DR'].unique()
array([1, 0, 2, 3]))
```

I would like to get the distinct counts and group by the state.

Example:

```
Alabama
0 12121
1 234
2 33
3 9
```

What is the best way of doing that? I was trying the following:

```
drunk.groupby(['state', 'DRUNK_DR']).count()
```

Did not work:

```
state   DRUNK_DR
Alabama 0
        1
        2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `value_counts()`:

```
df.groupby('state').DRUNK_DR.value_counts()

#state           DRUNK_DR
#California      0           1
#Illinois        0           1
#Indiana         0           1
#Nebraska        0           1
#New Mexico      1           1
#North Carolina  0           1
#Oklahoma        0           1
#South Carolina  0           1
#Tennessee       0           1
#Vermont         0           1
#Name: DRUNK_DR, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly it.

Comment: @Istvan if this answered your question, don't forget to select it as the chosen  answer.  Thanks.